# Field with Query based entity Data Type based on Entity from other App

Tags: 2sxc

**Goal**

I want to centralize Person based information within one 2sxc App and reuse the 'Persons' within other App's. Like a Person as an Author within a News-App and a Person as member within a Team-App and so on.

**What I did**

Create an App for Person administration (NPi_Person):

- Define a *Person* Content-Type with Fields like 'FullName', 'Phone' and so on.

In another App, for example an App for News (NPi_News):

- Define within the *News* Content-Type a Field *Person_Entity* with Datatype *Entity* and Input Type *Query based entity/item-picker*.
- Create a Query with DataSource *App* based on NPi_Person, retrieving the Content-Type *Person* (query_Person_from_NPi_Person).
- In *entity-query* definition of the *Person_Entity* Field refer to *query_Person_from_NPi_Person* and to the Stream (e.g. *Default*).

**Problem**

The dropdown of the Field *Person_Entity* of the NPi_News App contains as expected the *Person* Entities from the NPi_Person App. The problem is that the Person Entity doesn't get persisted. Means after saving and reopening the Form the Field *Person_Entity* is still empty.

Does this mean that the source of a Field with Datatype *Entity* and Input Type *Query based entity/item-picker* may not derive from another App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the entity field has relationships which are verified when loading the app into the cache. Each app is self-contained, so relationships are verified within that app only.

Entities from another app may or may not exist - it's something you must handle at runtime.

So to store these, you'll have to use the string-query and then look them up in your cshtml from the other app (or you can probably also do this using a query which looks them up from the string keys). It's also super-fast, but you need to manually do this as you're going beyond the default data-model.

Comment: I use now the *String* Data Type with Input Type *dropdown-query* as proposed. To keep the lookup robust I would like to use the *Id* as Value Field and the *FullName* as Label Field. The disadwantage with this is, that after reopen the Form the *Person* Field displays the *Id* (only).

Is there a way / query DataSource which allows to combine two fields in one calculated field like 
[FullName+' | '+Id] to use it as the Value Field?

Comment: as of now no. But this would be a cool feature - which would be implemented as a data-source in the query (something which would build new fields or something like that). I suggest you try to create that kind of a data source and then propose it to add to the core ;)

Comment: I would do it if I were able to :(

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts regarding an alternative use case of Person based information across App's: The goal in my initial question could be achieved by considering DNN User-accounts as such Persons. For this case you can use a *DnnUserProfile* Datasource. The *dropdown-query* Field Input Type could get the User's DisplayName as value for the Value Field. It's content is defined in DNN (Security.. Member Accounts.. Registration Settings). I would set it as *[FIRSTNAME] [LASTNAME] [[USERID]]*. This content is meaningful within the edit form and at the same time the USERID serves to look up user info from the App query at runtime. A drawback is you have to edit the content with DNN UI (url links [yourdomain]/ctl/profile/userid/[ID]).